# mp4Parser AppendExample gives NPE

Tags: java, mp4parser

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Create a movie, add an audio track and a video track of almost 3-4 mins.
2. Try to create the Container
3. It takes a lot of time and then gives a null pointer exception

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
Expected output is to get a container that I can write to a file. Instead I get a null pointer exception.

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
RC-27 on Windows 7, 4 GBs of RAM, Core i3 processor, jre v7u45

**Please provide any additional information below.**
Is there any limitation to sample size or samples count? Are there any limitations or hardware requirements to run it better?

I am using the code at : https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/AppendExample.java

Why is the NPE coming and what can I do to remove/debug it?

Snapshot of the error:
[image]